# Hi everyone i used laravel 9, i'm tried to use redirect route with compact method but i got error in my form "Undefined variable $data_save"

Tags: php, laravel-8

1- My web route:

```
Route::get('/register_visit','reception\add_visit@create')->name('create_visit');
```

2-My Controller

```
$datasave = new Model_patient;
         $datasave->f_name_en =  request('f_name_en');
         $datasave->l_name_en = request('l_name_en');
         $datasave->province = request('province');
         $datasave->save(); 
         $data_save = $datasave;
         return redirect()->route('create_visit')->with(compact('data_save'));
```

3-My blade.php

```
  @foreach ($data_save as $user)
         <p>This is f_name {{ $f_name->id }}</p>
  @endforeach
```

How we fix this error ? thank you !!!

Comment: Compact works with blade view files. You can't inject those into a route and expect those to be available for that route's blade files.

Comment: Hi @nice_dev ` return redirect()->route('create_visit');` i updated it like this but it still error in blade

Comment: Show the route and controller method code for `create_visit`.

Comment: controller

$datasave = new Model_patient;
         $datasave->f_name_en =  request('f_name_en');
         $datasave->l_name_en = request('l_name_en');
         $datasave->province = request('province');
         $datasave->save(); 
         $data_save = $datasave;
         return redirect()->route('create_visit');

Web.php
Route::get('/register_visit','reception\add_visit@create')->name('create_visit'); this is my updated code

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments. [Edit] your question and post relevant information/code there. Thanks